# MySQL - Inner Join Count from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

**Category**

| *id* | *name* | *case* |

**Items**

| *id* | *name* | *categoryid* | <-- this is the relation column

I'm tryig to show all categorys  with your respective number of items, like this:

Category Name: Abstract [15 items]

I'm using this code:

```
$getcategory = mysqli_query($con, "
SELECT c.name
     , c.id
     , c.case
     , i.id
     , COUNT(i.categoriaid) AS photos 
  FROM category c 
  JOIN items i
    ON c.id = i.categoriaid 
 WHERE i.id != '' 
 ORDER 
    BY c.id ASC 
");


while ($showcategory = mysqli_fetch_array($getcategory)) {
echo '
<div class="category-container">
<div class="category-title">'.$showcategory['name'].'</div>
<div class="category-img-container">
<div class="img-stretch"><img src="'.$showcategory['case'].'" alt=""/></div>
</div>
<div class="category-count"><div><span class="destaque alto">[ '.$showcategory['photos'].'  ]</span> telas</div></div>
</div>
';
}
```

But this don't work. What's wrong?

Comment: *"But this don't work. What's wrong?"* - Can you define that? Are you getting errors? Are you getting any results? If any, what results are you looking to get?

Comment: and why are there 2 here? `FROM category category`

Comment: Then you have `items.categoriaid` yet your items table shows as `categoryid` same for `COUNT(items.categoriaid)`

Comment: See what the manual has to say about COUNT

Answer (score 0):

The query doesn't look right. There's an aggregate in the SELECT list, and no GROUP BY clause. If the query returns a result, it's going to be a single row. And it doesn't make sense to return non-aggregates in the SELECT list, if we're just going to return a COUNT.

Assuming that `id` is the PRIMARY KEY (or a UNIQUE KEY) in the `category` table, if sql_mode doesn't include ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, we might be able to get this to run:

```
  SELECT c.name
       , c.id
       , c.case
       , MIN(i.id) AS min_id
       , MAX(i.id) AS max_id
       , COUNT(i.categoriaid) AS photos
    FROM category c
    LEFT
    JOIN items i
      ON i.categoriaid = c.id
     AND i.id <> ''
   GROUP BY c.id
   ORDER BY c.id
```

If sql_mode includes ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, we can either use aggregate functions (e.g. MIN or MAX) around c.name and c.case, or we can extend the GROUP BY clause to include those columns.

```
  SELECT c.name
       , c.id
       , c.case
       , MIN(i.id) AS min_id
       , MAX(i.id) AS max_id
       , COUNT(i.categoriaid) AS photos
    FROM category c
    LEFT
    JOIN items i
      ON i.categoriaid = c.id
     AND i.id <> ''
   GROUP
      BY c.id
       , c.name
       , c.case
   ORDER
      BY c.id
```

Without a specification, we're just guessing. There could any number of things "wrong" with this statement. As a example list: invalid table references, invalid column references (is there a column name `categoriaid` in the items table? I took that from the SQL in the question).

I suggest you take the SQL writing to another environment and get the SQL written and tested. Then bring that statement back into your PHP code. (Divide and conquer.)

Also, in the PHP code, we can *test* whether query execution was successful, by testing the return from `mysqli_query`.  If it's FALSE, then we know it wasn't successful, and we can retrieve the error with `mysqli_error` function.

```
$sql = "SELECT ... ";
if( !$getcategory = mysqli_query($con,$sql) ) { 
   // statement execution was not successful
   die mysqli_error($con);
}
```